# react-native-onesignal receive push notification without opening notification

Tags: reactjs, react-native, onesignal

I have checked [react-native-onesignal](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal) github README and it seems the only way to get the notification is to open which is through the [onNotificationOpened()](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal#android-usage) callback.

Their documentation stated that:

> When any notification is opened or received the callback `onNotification` is called passing an object with the notification data.

But `onNotification` clearly does not work.

Is there any way to get the notification without opening the push notification or enabling the in-app alert notification?

Answer (score 1):

The `onNotification` function will only be called when opening a notification or when one is received while the app is in focus.

If you need to handle a notification in the background before it is opened you will need to do so with native code.

**iOS** - set `content_available` to `true` on the OneSignal [create notification](http://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/notifications-create-notification) REST API POST call, this will fire the 
[- application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) selector.

**Android** - Setup a `NotificationExtenderService` by following the OneSignal [Background Data and Notification Overriding](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-notification-customizations#background-data-and-notification-overriding) instructions.

Comment: My android skills are very weak. I did try to do the `NotificationExtenderService` I just can't get it to work. If by any chance, can you create a sample repo? thanks

Comment: Additionally, you don't receive the the notification while the app is on focus unless you enable `OneSignal.enableNotificationsWhenActive(true);` which opens an alert.

Comment: @ryeballar Did you get it to work? Can you post a sample repo?

Comment: @jkasten Can you post a sample repo?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding implementation of `NotificationExtenderService` in android (not answering the original question, but the question asked by @ryeballar), as explained in https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-background-data-and-notification-overriding:

- I am getting notifications when the app is closed/swiped-out/not-started without implementing `NotificationExtenderService`
- However, in order to implement `NotificationExtenderService` you need to do the following (as described in the onesignal documentation referenced above, **note that there is a typo there, fixed below**):

  1. Create a file called `NotificationExtender.java` in `node_modules\react-native-onesignal\android\src\main\java\com\geektime\rnonesignalandroid`, with the following contents:

.

```
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationPayload;
package com.geektime.rnonesignalandroid;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationPayload;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationPayload;
import com.onesignal.NotificationExtenderService;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationReceivedResult;

public class NotificationExtender extends NotificationExtenderService {
   @Override
   protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {
        // Read properties from result.

      // Return true to stop the notification from displaying.
      return false;
   }
}
```

2. Add the following to `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`:

.

```
<service android:name=".NotificationExtender" 
   android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" 
   android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtenderService" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

3. rebuild your app