# Can we get un-read notifications inside app from onesignal using react-native?

Tags: react-native, onesignal

I have integrated OneSignal in ReactNative, now i am able to send and receive notifications. But after once notification is received into the mobile, then and there itself from the notification tray if user clears the notification without clicking it. Do we have any option to get all un-read notifications either with player_id and app_id

Looks like we can read the messages once we click on the notification which re-directs to the application.

I expect onesignal notifications should to able to retrieve the list of un-read notification using react-native sdk.

Can Someone help me with your ideas

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think that onesignal (any push notification for that matter) has the functionality of keeping track of the message status. I would suggest using a DB for that matter. Get the notification from server, store it in the DB with a status, and when the user reads it Update the status. 

Here is a link I found which will hopefully help you out/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357267/react-native-onesignal-receive-push-notification-without-opening-notification

Comment: Thanks for the update @Shah surely look into  the source